# Problem classifying ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading through the beginning of Gerald Teschl's "Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems" book on my own and was hoping to verify some answers to Problem 1.3 on page 8 and also ask questions about some of the problems to make sure I am understanding the definitions correctly.

> **Problem 1.3** Classify the following differential equations.  Is the equation linear, autonomous?  What is its order?
>
> (i) $y'(x) + y(x) = 0$
>
> (ii) $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} u(t) = t sin(u(t))$
>
> (iii) $y(t)^2 + 2y(t) = 0$
>
> (iv)  $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} u(x,y) = 0$
>
> (v) $\dot{x} = -y$, $\dot{y} = x$

My attempt:

(i)  linear, autonomous, first order

(ii)  nonlinear, non-autonomous, 2nd order

(iii) Is this a trick question??  The functional relation $y^2 - y = 0$ is not even an ODE!  0th order, non/linear?

(iv)  Teschl hasn't talked about the classification of PDE's yet so I am not quite sure what to do here.  I would guess linear, autonomous, and 2nd order?  (If this is correct, what would the order be if we only had a first derivative with respect to x and still had a 2nd order w.r.t. y?)

(v)  linear, autonomous, first order

Comment: I would agree with you on (iii), 0 order, nonlinear, autonomous.  I would also agree with you that it is a strange question to ask. I would also agree on with your classification of (iv).  In the hypothetical case you mention, it would still be second order.

Comment: Your solution is precisely what I had in mind. (iii) is no ODE and (iv) is a PDE.

Comment: Curious why the first equation is first-order? I thought it was zeroth-order since there isn't any derivative of the dependent variable $x$, only of $y$. Does the prime notation mean derivative with respect to $x$ or $t$?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it more, I think this is a first order linear, but not autonomous. In this case $x$ is the independent variable.